# iOS 7 does not call layoutSubviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7

I am transitioning my iOS 6 app to iOS 7 and have a few problems.

In iOS 6 methods would be called that are no longer called.

My class is inherited from UIAlertView.

For example:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
rezise the frame for the tableview
}
```

In iOS 7 this function gets no longer called resulting in my tableview not resizing (frame sticking at CGrectZero).

There are a few more methods that just wont be executed anymore.

Do i need to use another method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UIAlertView`'s view hierarchy is private and should not be modified, nor should `UIAlertView` be subclassed. In iOS 6 you got away with it, but not in iOS 7 anymore. Look at [SDCAlertView](http://github.com/Scott90/SDCAlertView). I wrote it to replace `UIAlertView`, keeping the looks and behaviors the same but with more functionality.

**EDIT**:

The exact reason that none of your layout methods get called, is because `UIAlertView` is never added to a view hierarchy. When you call `-[UIAlertView show]`, a separate window is created and made active, with a view hierarchy (presumably defined by UIAlertView) that contains all the different elements of an alert. Some of these elements are also used in other modal contexts, such as a popover, action sheet, form sheet modal on iPad, etc.

You can inspect all this yourself, and with some nasty hacking, you can modify the view hierarchy that way. However, that's absolutely not recommended as it could break at any time, even with a 7.x.y update.

Comment: oh well. i read about UIAlertView having hierarchy issues but i also read that i just needed to fiddle around where i put my code instead which did not work at all. thanks for the detailed discription of the problem. i found this too: https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview . does your reproduction handle rotation too?

Comment: Yes, rotation works just like the normal `UIAlertView`. The only real issues are alert queues and wrong positioning when a keyboard is shown (see the issues of the GitHub repository).